# Killing processes works differently for a .bat and a .sh file?

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

This question is a two-parter. Sorry about that. First question: If I use a bash script (`.sh`) and change directories within that script, then later on while the script is running and I kill it, I end up back at the directory I started in. However, when I try to do this in a `.bat` script, and I use `chdir` instead of `cd`, then kill the process, I am in the directory that I `chdir`'d to.  An example:

```
#runscript.sh
cd seconddir/thirddir/
# run some ongoing process here
----------------------------------
usr/firstdir> ./runscript.sh
[Ctrl + C]
usr/firstdir>
```

Then in the second case:

```
#runscript.bat
chdir seconddir/thirddir/
# run some ongoing process here
----------------------------------
usr/firstdir> runscript.bat
[Ctrl + C]
usr/firstdir/thirddir>
```

Why does this happen? Can I make the `.bat` script go back after the process is killed with `Ctrl + c`?

Comment: If you rename the .bat file to .cmd, does it behave differently? .bat is an old extension from the MS-DOS days, and as such some emulation makes it behave differently, whereas .cmd is modern.

Comment: Also, you label it windows, but your entire question screams Linux. What OS are you on?

Comment: @LPChip windows. why use a bat script in linux?

Comment: Windows paths use `C:\folder1\folder2` where you use a linux style path. Also sh scripts are not common on windows either, although not impossible. For that reason it seemed far more likely that you are using linux in combination with wine maybe. So that's why I asked.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. No, I'm on windows but for _reasons_ i have to have a .sh and a .bat script that do the same thing. To answer your first question, changing it to a .cmd doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The current directory is a property of a process. Different processes can have different current directories, and a process can't modify the current directory of another process.

When you open the command window (sometimes wrongly called DOS window), it starts `cmd.exe`. This `cmd.exe` can execute commands you type on the keyboard, as well as commands from a `.bat` or `.cmd` file. It doesn't know about `.sh` files.

The shell script `.sh` is executed by starting a shell, a different process, and the commands in the `.sh` file change the current directory of the shell process. It doesn't change the directory of the command interpreter `cmd.exe`.

The batch file is executed by the command interpreter `cmd.exe`, and therefor changes the current directory of the command interpreter. This change is still in effect after the execution of the batch file is finished.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the batch script to work like the shell script? I've tried doing the `cd` in a new process but it's not working.

Comment: No, you can't. It is working, but just in that new process.

Comment: Could you put the "same process" / "separate process" clarification in the answer itself? As it is right now... "shell" and "command interpreter" are just two names for the same thing, so the main answer just makes no sense like that.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question, other than providing information on how things work. I therefor posted an answer that actually gives the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a command prompt window, you create a session. If you run a batch file from that prompt, it will be launched inside of that session, altering that session. Given that a shell script requires a different interpreter to understand what happens inside that script, technically speaking, a new session is created when that script is launched, and as such, the chdir is not carried out of the session to the previous command prompt window, whereas with the .bat file run directly from that command prompt window, it is.

What you want to do is first start a new cmd process and execute the batch script in there. By doing so, any changes the script makes to the current directory are not transferred back to the earlier session, as they are different sessions.

You do this by running the following command:

```
cmd /c "runscript.bat"
```

The /c will open a new command window, execute the command, then terminate that window. If you use /k, it will do the same, except the window remains, which basically means, reuse the current window. Its really weird that /c is terminate and /k is continue, rather than /c = continue and /k = kill, but that's just Microsoft Logic.

Comment: This doesn't answer either part of the question. It doesn't mention shell scripts at all, and it doesn't answer why current directories work the way way they do.

Comment: @RalfFriedl your answer already explains how it works, so I only added this part of the answer to not explain it yet again. But I'll edit my answer for you so it makes a bit more sense as to why it works, even though it really is written there.